# Approximating 'big' ratio with 'small' ratio

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, approximation

Given a ratio $ \frac{m}{n}, p \in N, q \in N $ where either $m$ or $n$ (or both) is a very big number, how can we find a ratio $ \frac{p}{q}, p \in N, q \in N $ which estimates $ \frac{m}{n} $ up to $ v $ significant digits **and** p and q are the smallest possible ones?

Example 1: $ m = 333333337, n = 1000000000 $, the best estimation for $ \forall v \in [1..7] $ is $ \frac{p}{q} = \frac{1}{3} $

Example 2: $ m = 42857, n = 100000 $, the best estimation for all $ \forall v $ is $ \frac{p}{q} = \frac{3}{7} $

I came up with the brute-force solution which is just to try all the combinations of $ p $ and $ q $ starting from 1 with the possible optimizations like finding the corresponding q by picking values $ q_1 $ and $ q_2 $ such that the desired $ q $ (if any) should satisfy $ q_1 \leq q \leq q_2 $. I estimated the worst case speed of such algorithm in $ O(10^v) $, provided $ m, n $ have the same order of magnitude and $ v < log_{10}m $

I'm interested in a solution, possibly suboptimal, which is much faster than mine. The 'real' values for $ m, n \approx 10^{50}; v \approx 30 $

Comment: so for a given $\alpha=\frac{m}{n}$ and $v \in \mathbb{N}$ you want to find the minimal $q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is a $p \in \mathbb{N}$ that  $$|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}| \lt 10^{-v}$$ 
Is this right?

Comment: as other stated you should use continuous fractions. continous fraction will find $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{3}{7}$

Comment: Yes, you are correct, sorry for the delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction, perhaps?

At least 30 characters, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in continued fractions. Is there a way to fold continued fraction into a ratio $ \frac{p}{q}, p \in N, q \in N $? Will those p and q be minimal possible ones?

Comment: @Alex You just take the first few terms from the continued fraction and convert it to a normal fraction. For instance, for $\pi$ you get the continued fraction $[3; 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...]$ which gives you the convergents $3$, $\frac{22}{7}$, $\frac{333}{106}$, $\frac{355}{113}$ etc.

Comment: Looks like this should work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $m$ and $n$ are prime together

You can simplify the best approximation between the fractions $\frac{m'}{n'}$ with $m'=m-1,m,m+1$ and $n'=n-1,n,n+1$ and $m'$ not prime with $n'$

You can do it as long as it verifies the precision constraint.